# ASP .NET CORE 1.1.1 Dependency Injection Error

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I new in Asp .Net Core and I created App using it. I'm using generic repository in my project. But I have one error:

> Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext' while attempting to activate 'ECommerce.Repository.ProductRepository'.

**BaseRepository**

```
protected DbContext _dbContext;
    protected readonly DbSet<T> _dbSet;

    public BaseRepository(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _dbSet = dbContext.Set<T>();
    }
```

**Repository**

```
public partial class ProductRepository : BaseRepository<Product>, IProductRepository
{
    public ProductRepository(DbContext dbContext) : base(dbContext) { }
}
```

**Service**

```
public partial class ProductService : BaseService<Product>, IProductService
{
    private readonly IProductRepository _repository;
    private readonly IProductValidation _validation;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    public ProductService(IProductValidation validation, IProductRepository respository, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        : base(validation, respository, unitOfWork)
    {
        _repository = respository;
        _validation = validation;
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }
}
```

**Validation**

```
public partial class ProductValidation : BaseValidation<Product>, IProductValidation
{
    private readonly IProductRepository _productRepository;

    public ProductValidation(IProductRepository productRepository) : base(productRepository)
    {
    }
}
```

**Startup**

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ECommerceDbContext>(options =>
           options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();


        services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
        services.AddTransient<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>();
        services.AddTransient<IProductService, ProductService>();
        services.AddTransient<IProductValidation, ProductValidation>();
    }
```

**Controller**

```
private readonly IProductService _productService;

    public ValuesController(IProductService productService)
    {
        _productService = productService;
    }
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Product> Get()
    {
        return _productService.GetAll();
    }
```

Please tell me what wrong in my code. Thanks so much

P/s: this code work perfect in my previous project using Asp .Net 4.6 using Autofac

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comments of the other answer:

If you are certain that there is only **ONE** `DbContext` ever in your application, you can do

```
services.AddScoped<DbContext, ECommerceDbContext>();
```

or

```
services.AddScoped<DbContext>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<ECommerceDbContext>());
```

if you don't want that `DbContext` and `ECommerceDbContext` resolve to two different instances

Comment: can you explain more detail difference 2 method ?

Comment: Like I said in the post, the first one would resolve in two different instances. If you inject `SomeConstructor(DbContext context, ECommerceDbContext eContext)`, then `context == eContext` will evaluate to false, because they are different. The second method should evaluate to equal for the above example

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject your actual DbContext class, in this case `ECommerceDbContext`.

So change the constructor to:

```
public BaseRepository(ECommerceDbContext dbContext)
{
    _dbContext = dbContext;
    _dbSet = dbContext.Set<T>();
}
```

Comment: I can't do that.BaseRepository in project name Core and my app using it by DLL. I want use it in another project and I don't want change it.

Comment: Since they don't provide an overload that would allow you to set the service type, you would have to copy what EF Core does in AddDbContext(), and change it so that the service type is DbContext instead of the context type: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/09b1503ef94287784d1f8fb29da90cba2a891f5e/src/EFCore/EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L262

Comment: I register DbContext to ECommerceDbContext, it solved my problem..:)

Comment: Oh. Wait. Haha. I'm just dumb. :P